Is it possible to sync code over multiple devices?
I'm writing my bachelors thesis now and need to do some python programming (preferably in PyCharm). When I'm at the university I use my laptop to code, when I'm at home I use my PC. Now the question is, is there a way to sync the code between the devices, so I can easily switch from laptop to PC (and vice versa) and continue where I left coding?
I saw that git might work but I didn't find it very intuitive, so is there an easier option?
I tried using Seafile and syncing the whole project there, but then the paths to python from both devices got mixed up (I think the path is somewhere written in the venv and is not the same on PC and laptop) and it didn't work.

... stay with git.

Learning a bit of git will let you perform the basic tasks you seem to need. Nothing too overwhelming unless you're going into more complex features designed for more advanced workflows. Initing a repo on existing code, pushing, cloning are simple operations, very well documented.

You can use a cloud base code editor like Codesandbox
That being said, I highly recommend learning to use Git, as it is an industry standard for version control.
